# LoginActivity fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

How do I change this so I won't have an error on case 0?

My login was a fragment, but I had to change it into an activity and now I have this problem - cannot find symbol class LoginFragment because of course, it's Activity now.

```
public void replaceFragmentDropDownMenu(int i) {
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  TextView headerName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.HeaderName);

  switch (i) {
    // Home Fragment - Not yet done
    case 0:
      headerName.setText("Member Login");
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new LoginActivity());
      break;
    // My Account - Not yet done
    case 1:
      headerName.setText("My Account");
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new RegisterFragment());
      break;
    // Search Dispensaries - Not yet done
```

Comment: Instead of  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new LoginActivity()); this line write code for start LoginActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do fragment transactions with activity objects you should launch activity by `startActivity()` method

```
case 0:
            headerName.setText("Member Login");
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            break;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but now all R.id.main_container became red. why did I get an error on R?

Comment: I think your build failed. Just rebuild from Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace an Activity into a FragmentTransaction. You will need to display the Activity by itself using startActivity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```